# Unable to create a Powershell Alias in a binary Module

Tags: powershell

I'd like export an alias from a binary module that I've created. For script modules, you'd use
`Export-ModuleMember`. Is there an equivalent for binary modules?

My manifest (.psd1) looks something like this:

```
@{
    ModuleToProcess = 'MyModule.psm1'
    NestedModules = 'MyModule.dll'
    ModuleVersion = '1.0'
    GUID = 'bb0ae680-5c5f-414c-961a-dce366144546'
    Author = 'Me'
    CompanyName = 'ACME'
    Copyright = '© ACME'
}
```

**EDIT**: [Keith Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153982/keith-hill) provided some help, but still to no avail. Here are all the files involved

My module script (.psm1):

```
export-modulemember -function Get-TestCommand -alias gtc
```

and finally, the code in my DLL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyModule
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "TestCommand")]
    [OutputType(typeof(string))]
    public class GetTestCommand : PSCmdlet
    {
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            WriteObject("One");
            WriteObject("Two");
            WriteObject("Three");
        }
    }
}
```

If I have this and fire up PowerShell, then `import-module MyModule` and finally run `get-module`, I get this:

```
ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Script     MyModule                  {}
```

If I comment out the `export-modulemember` bit in the psm1 file and repeat the above steps, I get this:

```
ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Script     MyModule                  Get-TestCommand
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The output of Get-Module doesn't show aliases by default.  Try this: `Get-Module MyModule | Foreach {$_.ExportedAliases}` or simply `gmo MyModule | fl`.

Comment: It's the missing ExportedCommands that are concerning me, not the aliases

Comment: Where is your CmdletsToExport setting in the PSD1 file? Also don't export the cmdlet from the PSM1 file using Export-ModuleMember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to make a .PSM1 your ModuleToProcess and put the Set-Alias / Export-ModuleMember -Alias * in that PSM1 file.  Then put your DLL reference into the PSD1's NestedModules member e.g.:

```
@{
    ModuleToProcess = 'MyModule.psm1'
    NestedModules   = 'MyModule.dll'
    ModuleVersion = '1.0'
    GUID = 'bb0ae680-5c5f-414c-961a-dce366144546'
    Author = 'Me'
    CompanyName = 'ACME'
    Copyright = '© ACME'
    FormatsToProcess = 'MyModule.format.ps1xml'
    AliasesToExport = '*'
    CmdletsToExport = @(
        'Get-Foo',
        'Set-Foo',
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but didn't have any luck. If I leave the .psm1 file completely empty, my functions in the .dll still export correctly. As soon as I place a export-module in the .psm1, regardless of what parameters I give, my functions are no longer exported.

Comment: The .PSM1's Export-ModuleMember should not affect what is exported from the DLL.  That is controlled by the `CmdletsToExport = @('get-foo', 'set-foo', ...)` member of the manifest file.  BTW while you could just use '*', your module will work better with PowerShell V3's new module auto-loading feature.

Comment: Nope, still no joy. I've updated the question to reflect the current status

Comment: Well, all I can say is that this is how we do it for the PowerShell Community Extensions. Works just fine there. You can see the PSD1 here: http://pscx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/100892#1357945  and the PSM1 here: http://pscx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/100892#1011399

Comment: Thanks Keith. Your help was invaluable

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've got it working now. It turns out there were a few mistakes that I made, all of which contributed to the problem.

- Problem 1: I don't understand PowerShell nearly as well as I'd like!
- Problem 2: I was confusing Functions and Cmdlets. I needed to specify `Export-ModuleMember -Cmdlet Get-TestCommand`, rather than `Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-TestCommand`. This explains why my ExportedCommand disappeared everytime I uncommented the `Export-ModuleMember` line. Keith Hill's links to the PSCE files helped me discover that.

  ```
  Functionality in a DLL = -Cmdlet
  Functionality in .psm1 = -Function
  ```
- Problem 3: It doesn't help exporting aliases if you haven't defined any. You need to set the aliases with `Set-Alias` first, then export it with `Export-Module`. This was a silly mistake on my part

So , in the end, changing my .psm1 file to the one shown below fixed the problem

```
Set-Alias gtc Get-TestCommand
Export-ModuleMember -Alias * -Function * -Cmdlet *
```

I'm going to give Keith credit for the answer. It's only because of his effort that I was able to get this going